# Is there any way to make yourself invisible to mobs on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm playing a technic mod pack and it has orespawn on it. Well I'm trying to steal from the ore tree but the queen keeps aggroing on me no matter where I go. I know its supposed to be difficult but is there any way to make myself untargetable by the queen even if its only for a brief second?

Answer (score 3):

Mods are kind of a sticky topic when trying to answer a question mainly because we don't know exactly how yours work because they differentiate from one another so drastically. But, from what I know there are many solutions to mobs in traditional vanilla minecraft which could be a solution to your problem.

**Option 1**

Make a potion. Many potions are provided in minecraft to help the players traverse around or eliminate problems. For example, create an invisibility potion to bypass particularly sticky situatuations, in your case, the queen.

**Option 2**

If at all possible kill the queen using your resources, throw her off a cliff, kill it with fire, smack it with your sword, poison it, killing an annoying mob is better than to sneak around it or ignore it.

**Option 3**

You can also most likely make the queen unable to reach you, for example, trap it in a pit, use your surroundings to your advantage.

**Option 4**

Lastly, you could cheat to make your way through. Though, this reduces from the game's quality you can use console codes to make yourself invisible to the queen.

In conclusion, use your smarts to try and outwit or kill the queen to obtain your loot, and if it must be resorted to, use console commands to get your loot. Hope this helped.

Comment: When using an invis. potion and you're carrying something (eg. weapon, wearing armour) there is a chance the mob can see you.